# Only files with binary content can be downloaded when trying to get images from Google Drive

Tags: reactjs, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get a folder of images from google drive, I'm usint react-google-drive-picker to select the folder then I run a request by id to get the content of it, but I get this error:

```
Only files with binary content can be downloaded. Use Export with Docs Editors files.
```

This is my code:

```
const [openPicker, data, authResponse] = useDrivePicker();

const handleOpenPicker = () => {
        openPicker({
        clientId: CLIENT,
        developerKey: API_KEY,
        viewId: "FOLDERS",
        showUploadView: true,
        showUploadFolders: true,
        setSelectFolderEnabled: true,
        supportDrives: true,
        multiselect: true,
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if(data){
            const request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
                'fileId': data.docs && data.docs[0] && data.docs[0].id,
                'mimeType': 'image/*',
                'alt': 'media'
            });

            request.execute((res: any) => {
                console.log('res', res);
                setImageList(res.name)
            }).catch((err: any) => {
                console.log('err', err)
            })
        }
      }, [data])
```

Comment: The error you are experiencing is actually caused by trying to download a Google Docs file (Spreadsheet, Document, etc.) that's why it is recommending you to use export instead since you first need to export the google docs before being able to download them.

First, confirm the IDs that they are indeed non-Google Docs then show them on your post to further reduce the possible causes of the issue.